# How to filter the datatable column which is not equal to the text entered into filter textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a datatable individual column filter requirement where,I need to filter the column which is not equal to the text entered into filter textbox.. How to get this?

```
$("body").on( 'keyup change','.dataTables_scrollFoot tfoot input', function () {    
    var table = $('myTableDiv').find('table').DataTable();
    table
    .column( $(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
    .search( this.value )
    .draw();
} );
```